# Which equation represents quadratic time

Tags: java, big-o, quadratic

[image]

I believe it is 3n+5n^2+1 but I am not 100 percent sure. If I am wrong can someone explain to me why?

Comment: you are correct

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a math question, not computing

Comment: Big O Notation is a math question? I

Comment: @hotrod28 Not necessarily, but this is a maths question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3n + 5n^2 + 1          | applying Big-O notation for the single terms

= O(3n) + O(5n^2) + O(1) | leaving out constant multipliers

= O(n) + O(n^2) + O(1)   | taking the one with the maximum power

= O(n^2)

=> quadratic time

So you are right, the first option is the quadratic one.

If it was 3n + 5n^(2 + 1), then it would be qubical due to 5^(2 + 1) = 5^3.